# Docker image (Ubuntu: Netbeans, MySql Server)

Tags: docker

Please, i'd like to create a docker image to my students containing (ubuntu, Netbeans (with Glassfish) and MySql Server). Then, i'd like to deploy it on the hub and my students will be able to download this image.

Is that possible ? And i ask if there is in this case a tutorial that can help me ?

Thank you so much for answer. 
Kind regards.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but that's not really what docker is for.  If you would like to create consistent development environment, [Vagrant](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/) is probably a better way to go.

Comment: @R0MANARMY "that's not really what docker is for", can you please give me more details ? Thanks.

Comment: I would start [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9863538).  There is also a pretty good writeup on creating a development environment [here](https://blog.codeship.com/cross-platform-docker-development-environment/). The question you should ask is *how can I create a consistent development environment for my students*.